# Is it possible to check if a TCP connection disconnected without writing to it?

Tags: perl, networking, tcp

I am wondering if it possible to determine if an accepted socket connection has been disconnected without trying to write to it.

[IO::Select](https://www.metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aSelect) still indicates that the socket can be written to with can_write, even after the socket connection has been lost.

Is it possible to check if a TCP connection has been disconnected without writing to it (in the situation where there is an unplanned internet outage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a TCP than a Perl issue.

Events like a disconnected cable/internet connection do not lead to a TCP event. Thus you must write to a TCP connection to be sure that it is still connected. You might add a ping/echo message for the sole porpose to know that the connection is still available.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling that was the case, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. You'll usually only get a failure when you write: if you never write, it will just sit there. If you entirely lose network connectivity I've seen errors pop up (on Windows: haven't tried it on Linux) but you're typically required to try writing to it to verify that its alive.